# Prove: If $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a countable collection of sets in $\mathcal{A}$, then $m(\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k)$.

Tags: analysis

The following proof question is from H.L. Royden and P.M. Fitzpatrick's "Real Analysis", 4th ed. It is problem 3 in section 2.1, page 31.

> In this problem, let $m:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow [0,\infty)$ be a set function where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra (defined on p. 19). Assume $m$ is countably additive over countable disjoint collections of sets in $\mathcal{A}$.
>
> Problem:
>
> If $\{E_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ is a countable collection of sets in $\mathcal{A}$, then $m(\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty m(E_k)$.

Proof attempt:

> Let us define each term in this collection the following way:
>   \begin{align*}
> E_1 &= \emptyset + (E_1-\emptyset) \\ 
> E_2 &= E_1 + (E_2-E_1) \\
> E_3 &= E_2 + (E_3-E_2) \\
> \vdots &=\qquad \vdots \\
> E_k &= E_{k-1} + (E_k - E_{k-1}) \\
> \end{align*}
>
> Adding these equations in columns, we get
>
> $\sum_{k=1}^\infty E_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty E_{k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (E_k - E_{k-1})$
>
> (where $E_0=\emptyset$.)
>
> (unable, so far, to find a way to use this, but the following note that I have made seems important)
>
> Note: $\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty E_k - \cap_{k=1}^\infty E_k$,
>
> so clearly $\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty E_k$.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is simple (I do not fully understand your notation with sums of sets).
Define
$$
A_1 := E_1,\quad
A_2 := E_2 \setminus E_1,
\quad\ldots\quad
A_n := E_n \setminus (E_1 \cup \cdots \cup E_{n-1}),
\quad\ldots
$$
so that $(A_n)$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint measurable sets, with
$$
A_n\subseteq E_n \quad \forall n, \qquad \cup_n A_n = \cup_n E_n.
$$
Using the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$ and its monotonicity you have
$$
\mu(\cup_n E_n) = \mu(\cup_n A_n) = \sum_n \mu(A_n)\leq \sum_n \mu(E_n).
$$